# How can I sort posts by date in my web application in Django?

Tags: django, sql-order-by

I have a web application and I was trying to order it by most recent date, that is, the most current above and the oldest dates below, but for some reason it orders me the other way around and on other computers it orders well, the strange thing is that on my local server it is fine, it orders me as I want but at the time of showing it on the website it shows as I had mentioned before.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Publicacion(models.Model):
    foto = models.ImageField()
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    contenido = models.TextField()
    fecha = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    contenido_largo = models.TextField(max_length=10000, default='', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titulo
```

views.py

```
class ListarPublicaciones(ListView):
    model = Publicacion
    template_name = 'Publicacion/listarPublicaciones.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            pedidos = Pedido.objects.filter(cliente = self.request.user).aggregate(Sum('cantidad'))
            context['Pedido'] = pedidos
            context['object_list'] = Publicacion.objects.all().order_by('-fecha')
        return context
```

I have tried with order_by('-fecha__year','-fecha__month','-fecha__day')

html

```
<section class="py-5"><!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container"><!-- Container página principal -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12"> 
      <div class="panel">
        {% for p in object_list %}
          <div class="row">    
            <br>
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 text-center">
                  <a class="story-img" href="{% url 'publicacion:detallePublicacion' p.pk %}">
                <img src="{{p.foto.url}}" class="rounded" style="width: 250px;"></a>
              </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-9">
              <a class="subt" href="{% url 'publicacion:detallePublicacion' p.pk %}"><h2>{{p.titulo}}</h2></a>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <p class="texto">{{p.contenido|urlize}}</p>
                  <div class="redes list_op" style="text-align: right;">
                    <ul class="list-inline list-unstyled" >
                      {% if p.contenido_largo %}
                      <li>
                        <a class="plus" href="{% url 'publicacion:detallePublicacion' p.pk %}">Ver más</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>|</li>
                      {% endif %} 

                      <li>{{p.fecha.day}}-{{p.fecha.month}}-{{p.fecha.year}}</li>
                      <li>|</li>
                      <li>
                    <i class="fa fa-share" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 12px; color: #2c5d63;"></i> Compartir:
                    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://feriacultiva.com/publicaciones/detallepublicacion/{{p.pk}}"><img src="{% static 'icon/facebook.png' %}" border=0 height="25" class="facebook" /></a>
                    <a href="whatsapp://send?text=http:http://feriacultiva.com/publicaciones/detallepublicacion/{{p.pk}}" data-action="share/whatsapp/share"><img class="whatsapp" border="0" src="{% static 'icon/whatsapp.png' %}"></a>
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=¡Mira%20esta%20publicación%20de%20Feria%20Cultiva!&url=http://feriacultiva.com/publicaciones/detallepublicacion/{{p.pk}}" target="_blank"><img class="twitter" border="0" src="{% static 'icon/twitter.png' %}" height="25"></a>
                  </li>
                  
                    </ul>
                  </div>        
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                </div>
              </div>
              <br><br>
            </div>
          </div>
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be resolved by using '''DateTimeField'''
Then '''order_by''' will work
Replace and remigrate it works fine for me